# Remove files from source after copy to dest

Tags: linux, rsync

I have two folders, let's call them `/local` and `/amazon` which are bound under `/unionfs`.

Every 6 hours, I have an rsync that runs (via cron) that copies any files that exist in `/local` to `/amazon`.

Storage is limited on `/local` and plentiful on `/amazon`.

Is there a way to programatically delete a file that exists on `/amazon` in `/local`?

[Something similar to this](https://superuser.com/questions/1108494/deleting-all-files-from-source-directory-after-robocopy-but-retaining-those-tha) but for Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the option `--remove-source-files`, read the explanation of `rsync --remove-source-files` [here](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync%20--remove-source-files)

rsync will only remove successful transferred files. From the manual:

> --remove-source-files
>   This tells rsync to remove from the sending side the files (meaning non-directories) that are a part of the transfer and have been successfully duplicated on the receiving side.

Also note the manual states to not try to transfer files currently being written, see [explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync%20--remove-source-files).

Comment: Would this remove files that errored when transfering?